# How to replace one double inverted quote with two single inverted qoutes in java

Tags: java

I want a sample program which will replace the double inverted quote to 2 single inverted quotes.

Example:

Input :

```
"hello","my name is XYZ"
```

Output:

```
``hello'',``my name is XYZ''
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Someone may decide to do your work for you.

Comment: @RobertMoskal I really need it , its important for project . i m hoping some one will fast on this

Comment: @prabhatyadav, next time you post a question, I recommend that you include what you have tried and what exactly you are stuck on.

Comment: sure i will next time attach what i have done .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regular expressions as follows:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\"(.*?)\"", "``$1''");
```

(Note that any unmatched `"` in the end will be left as is.)

[ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/Aq5uaQ)